# Function wait for a loop before returning value in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, modern-experience, typescript

My function return value of an array before pushing value into array.

```
private async getPPickerid(ppvalue,AssignedToIdArr):Promise<any> {
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  ppvalue.forEach(async(element ,i) => {
    var user = await this.GetUserIdPPicker(element.Key);
    console.log(user.d.Id);
     AssignedToIdArr.push(user.d.Id); 
  })
resolve(AssignedToIdArr);
})
```

Function doesn't wait for the loop to be completed for pushing the value into array.

Instead It resolved the blank array and then array. Push work.

I have used async-await but not getting any way for function to wait for loop and then get resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
private async function getPPickerid(ppvalue: any[], AssignedToIdArr: any[]): Promise<any[]> {
  for (let index = 0; index < ppvalue.length; index++) {
    let user = await this.GetUserIdPPicker(ppvalue[index].Key);
    console.log(user.d.Id);
    AssignedToIdArr.push(user.d.Id);
  }
  return AssignedToIdArr;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked